# the name 'when' does not exist in the context

Tags: exception, c#-6.0

I tried implementing the exception filters in C#.

```
try
{
 //do Stuffs
}

catch (Exception ex)  when (ex is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException  || ex is SomeException);
{
   //Handle the caught errors
}
```

I get an error saying, the name 'when' does not exist in the context with a red squiggly line under the word 'when'.

I even checked the version of c#, it is C# 6.

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting C# 6 or higher? And you'll need to the `;` at the end of the `when` clause.

Comment: I see no new information was added to the question. Exception filters do work in C# 6. Either you are targeting the wrong language version or you are using an old Resharper version that doesn't recognize C# 6.